# Filtering through data

Tags: javascript, dojo

I currently have a set of json data that I wish to filter through, however it does not work when i attempt to filter through it & shows an error: ' TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function '

Here's a snippet:

```
load: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var titlePane = new TitlePane({
            title: data[i].Name ,
            open: false,
            content: '<div>' + data[i].Summary  +   '</div>'
        });
        titlePane.placeAt(dom.byId('licenseContainer'));
        titlePane.filter({ Archived:true });
    }
 },
```

As you can see I only want to have the json data that are archived to be displayed.

Here's a snippet of my json data:

```
  [ {"Name":"james", "Archived":true, "Summary": "sfksfsd"}, {"Name":"kay", "Archived":false, "Summary": "sfksfsd"}, {"Name":"greg", "Archived":true, "Summary": "sfksfsd"}           ]
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Show us the line where the error appears.

Comment: I only receive an error from my built in error function, therefore, I cannot tell you the line. But, I assume I'm not doing the filtering correctly as when I added it - the error appeared. So titlePane.filter etc ...

Comment: I don't know what kind of object `TitlePane` is, but you seem to be trying to filter on an non-existing property. Your `data` has an `Archived` key, but are you sure `TitlePane` has one too? You're not passing it to the constructor...

Comment: if [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TitlePane.html#id2) is the right kind of `TitlePane`, it doesn't looks like there's such a method as `placeAt` *or* `filter`...

Comment: I tried  data.filter({ Archived:true }) .. but no luck with that at all.

Comment: if you take off the filter function - everything works. But, no sure what I need to change on the filter function.

Comment: Never mind, there is a `placeAt` but no `filter` according to the [api](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dijit/TitlePane) documentation. So `filter` would be undefined... Am I missing something here? What are you expecting `filter` to do?

Comment: No you are correct. I just wanted to all show the names that are ' archived:true'. I possibly will need to do this instead http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/array.html#dojo-base-array-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Update function to do what I assume the OP wants the filter method to do for him.

You call a function `dom.byId` when I think you really meant to say `dojo.byId` Your function should in fact look like this:

```javascript
load: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Archived) {
            var titlePane = new TitlePane({
                title: data[i].Name,
                open: false,
                content: '<div>' + data[i].Summary + '</div>'
            });
            titlePane.placeAt(dojo.byId('licenseContainer'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No @jeff just pointed out that it doesnt have a filter method unfortunately. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Sure, don't use a method that doesn't exist! But other than that, what are you expecting the filter method to do for you? Don't add the title pane to the DOM if the user is archived?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am now attempting to try something like this: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/array.html#dojo-base-array-filter

Comment: I just updated the function to only add a title pane if the user is archived. You shouldn't have to use a filter.